# How to control rviz view parameters programatically?

Tags: ros, rviz, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to control the rviz view parameters programatically from an external node, for instance:
Set the view type to topDownOrtho and set the scale parameter to 10 and angle to 3.14.

I guess that this is possible to control these parameters using the rviz.h library , but what I essentially wonder is if there is something already developed to control rviz from an external node via topics.

Otherwise, how would you develop a system that it is able to control these parameters from a python node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241332/how-to-control-rviz-view-parameters-programatically?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-08**:
There are some view controllers for rviz which either track a frame or are controllable from data published on a ROS topic. I don't know the details, but most of them are packaged as rviz plugins outside of the stock rviz package.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-08-08**:
Interesting, I will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably use the [rviz_animated_view_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_animated_view_controller) for this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-08-09**:
This looks promising. I will try it and I will notify how it works.